# MOXy support for JSON Pointer (RFC6901) in Jersey

Tags: java, json, jersey, moxy

I'm trying to marshal a recursive bean to JSON with MOXy in Jersey, following the specification of RFC6901 aka JSON Pointer.

E.g., I'd like to marshal this:

```
   public class Bean {
     public Integer id;
     public String name;
     public Bean other;
     public List<Bean> next;
   }

   x = new Bean(123, "X");
   a = new Bean(456, "A");
   x.other = a;
   x.next.add(x);
   x.next.add(a);
```

into this:

```
   {
     "id": 123,
     "name": "X",
     "a": { "id": 456, "name": "A", "next": [ ] },
     "next": [
       { "$ref": "#" },
       { "$ref": "#/a" }
     ]
  }
```

and then unmarshal this JSON to the original bean. Does someone have any suggestion/solution to this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure if MOXy supports it, but [Jackson seems to have a support for it](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonPointer.java).